# Wordpress AJAX / PHP $_POST object is always empty

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

This seems like more of a PHP problem than a Wordpress one, but it's on a server running WP so I'm including it just in case.

I have a JS object like so:

```
{
  "Name": "Test Names",
  "Company": "Test Company",
  "Email": "TestEmail@mail.com",
  "Phone": "234556",
  "FoundPlattarHow": "Internet",
  "Interest": "Building",
  "ReceiveUpdates": "1"
}
```

At present I just have a blank PHP file, at `/lib/contact.php`:

```
<?php 
    echo "HELLO" . $_POST['Email'];
    prettyPrint($_POST);        

    function prettyPrint($a) {
        echo "\n";
        print_r($a);
        echo "\n";
    }

?>
```

I'm using POSTMAN (results are the same when I do an actual AJAX request form my browser), and sending the JS above as `application/JSON` as a POST request to the script.

The output I get is:

```
HELLO
Array
(
)
```

So it seems as though none of my data is actually coming through at all. What am I doing wrong here?!

Comment: What does your form code look like? Seems there's a lot of missing code to get a clear idea of what's going on, and what your problem is.

Answer (score 5):

You're sending the data in the request body with "Content-type: application/json" headers. In that case you should use method below,

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$json = json_decode($data, true);
var_dump($json);
```